# Timespan division by a number

Tags: c#, timespan

I have a code generating a timespan to calculate a duration of some action.
What I want to do is to take that result (the duration) and divide it by a number, any number.

How can I do that?

Comment: I tried casting, but the compiler returns an error. If I get a result of 0.0000000004, I want to divide that number, lets say, in 4. This is just an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiply TimeSpan in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909086/multiply-timespan-in-net)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
TimeSpan X = ...;

var Result = X.TotalMilliseconds / WhatEverNumber;
```

For reference see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx).

Comment: This will give you a double, not a TimeSpan. See the other answers.

Answer (score 37):

You can use ticks of the original timespan:

```
var res = new TimeSpan(origSpan.Ticks / aNumberAnyNumber);
```

Comment: Upvoting because that's the first integer division answer, which, when available, is almost always a better choice.

Comment: For all VB.NET developers who happen to stumble across this useful answer: the division operator is an _integer_ division, so use VB's \ operator (backslash) to avoid an error _Option Strict On disallows implicit conversion from 'Double' to 'Long'_.

Answer (score 9):

```
TimeSpan ts = ...
TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.FromTicks(ts.Ticks / divisor);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use one of the `Total*` properties of the `TimeSpan` which are numbers.

I.e. if you're running five iterations of some code which you measure, then you can use

```
myTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds / 5
```

to get the average number of milliseconds per iteration. You can use the `Ticks` to get the underlying value and construct a new `TimeSpan` from the divided result.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to end up with a new TimeSpan that is a fraction of the old:

```
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan halfOfNow = new TimeSpan(now.Ticks / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to divide, but let's say you want seconds, you can use the totalseconds property.

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0);  //Four hours

MessageBox.Show((ts.TotalSeconds / 4).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Division is now supported by `TimeSpan` as of .NET Standard 2.1.

Example usage:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = ...
int divisor = ...
TimeSpan result = timeSpan / divisor;
```

Comment: P\roblem with the default method is that it returns `double` instead of `TimeSpan` if you attempt to divide `TimeSpan` by `TimeSpan`. See other answers.

Answer (score 0):

To add more on the already answers, you can use the "Divide" [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.divide?view=net-7.0).

```
public TimeSpan Divide (double divisor);
```

But you will need to convert your int to double.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a way to divide a TimeSpan to a new TimeSpan without getting fractional seconds.
Based on what I found here I came up with:

```
TimeSpan DivTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((long)SourceTime.TotalSeconds / divisor);
```