# How to get the percentage of time in hours...?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timespan

I am developing a web application using asp.net c#. 
In that I need to get the percentage of Time. 
I am not getting the correct way to accomplish this. I have TotalHours which is coming from db. I need to calculate the 80% of that TotalHours.

Help will be appreciated.
Thanks...

```
//This is how I am getting the TotalTime
TimeSpan TotalTime = TimeSpan.Parse(totalhours);

if(TotalTime != null)
{

TimeSpan Percentage= ( TotalTime* 80 ) / 100;
// here I need to get correct percentage in hrs
// If TotalTime is 10 hrs then Percentage should be 8 hrs 

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiply TimeSpan in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909086/multiply-timespan-in-net)

Comment: If it's coming from the db, you should not be calling `TimeSpan.Parse` because you should not store time as strings in your db.  Instead, determine the precision you care about (ex, minutes) and store an integer number of that precision.  Then use `TimeSpan.FromMinutes`, `TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`, or similar methods for other precisions.

Answer (score 3):

```
TimeSpan TotalTime = TimeSpan.Parse("10:00:00");

if (TotalTime != null)
{
    var ticks = ((TotalTime.Ticks * 80) / 100);
    TimeSpan Percentage = new TimeSpan(ticks);
    Console.WriteLine(Percentage);  // 8 hours
}
```

Comment: Plus 1. I like this as it takes total time i.e. Ticks and not just hours.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal yeh, I wrote the same thing 7 mins ago, but whatever :)

Comment: Plus 1 to you too @msmolcic.

Answer (score 2):

```
TimeSpan totalTime = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0);
TimeSpan percentage = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((totalTime.TotalMilliseconds * 80) / 100);
```

Get total miliseconds from your totalTime, do the math and convert it back to `TimeSpan` from miliseconds.

If you're satisfied with hours simply change:

```
TimeSpan percentage = TimeSpan.FromHours((totalTime.TotalHours * 80) / 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`TotalHours` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `TimeSpan` returns total number of hours as a `double`. That's why you can calcutate %80 of your `TimeSpan` like;

```
double Percentage = (TotalTime.TotalHours * 4) / 5;
```